# SSIS excel source not reading excel workbook sheets

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that reads data from multiple Excel sheets in a workbook. As of Friday, the package was reading data from the excel sheets just fine only to return today and suddenly the Excel Source can no longer see the sheets in the workbook.

In the Excel Source Editor, I have set the OLE DB Connection Manager and the Data Access Mode to Table or View but the name of the excel sheet dropdownlist is empty.

It brings a message that "No tables or views could be loaded". I changed nothing in this project, it simply just stopped working on its own. I did get lots of updates today though, so my guess is that it could some update problem.

See the error i am getting below.

> > Error at Package ["Excel Connection manager"]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
> >     0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft JET
> >     Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified
> >     error".
>
> Error at Country [Excel Source [649]]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps below resolved the issue, i guess a windows update screwed my office installation

1. Uninstall the Jet Engine pack on your development XP machine if you have Office. It will be listed as something like "Microsoft Access Database Engine (2010)".
2. Run Office 200x setup with the Repair option and reboot.
3. Try configuring the task in SSIS and it should be able to read the Sheet names again and columns.

Source
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eae00a90-8c64-4337-8027-b7f4b342fcd8/excel-data-source-ssis-acquireconnection-failed-0x80004005-unspecified-error?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Thankyou for posting your solution, you make the internet a better place

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using the 64 bit of Access Database engine, Uninstall Access Database engine 32 bit and this should solve your issue.

[click here to download 32 bit Access Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255)